# java program has error after "bootlean go=true"?

Tags: java, loops

I'm getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at package1.smth.main(clas1.java:19)
```

When I remove the `while(go)` part, everything is working fine. But I added it to be able to reset program, and now there is an exception. I also have a code for another similar program, where I added the same loop and it is working without this exception.
Can someone explain what's the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean go = true;
    while (go) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double a = 0;
        double b = 0;
        double c = 0;
        double discriminant = 0;
        double d = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter a : ");
        a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter b : ");
        b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Enter c : ");
        c = input.nextDouble();
        discriminant = (b * b - 4 * a * c);
        d = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
        if (discriminant >= 0.0) {
            System.out.println("first answer : " + (-b + d) / (2.0 * a));
            System.out.println("second answer : " + (-b - d) / (2.0 * a));
        } else if (discriminant == 0.0) {
            System.out.println("first answer : " + (-b) / (2.0 * a));
            System.out.println("second answer : " + (-b) / (2.0 * a));
        } else {
            System.out.println("no asnwers.");
            input.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've read everything I could find similar to my problem, and most answers came from this site. I tried to implement the given solutions to my code, and some didn't work, some I could not understand how to use because my code is different from the example in a question. I am total newbie, it is probably third program I wrote.

---

**UPDATE:**
The final code I have. The only problem it shows, is *"leak: scanner not closed"*.

```
package gg;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class hbh {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean go = true;
        while (go) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            double a = 0;
            double b = 0;
            double c = 0;
            double discriminant = 0;
            double d = 0;

            System.out.print("Enter a: "); 
            a = input.nextDouble(); 

            System.out.print("Enter b: "); 
            b = input.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter c: "); 
            c = input.nextDouble();

            discriminant = (b * b - 4 * a * c);

            d = Math.sqrt(discriminant);
            if (discriminant >= 0.0) {
                System.out.println("First answer: " + (-b + d) / (2.0*a));
                System.out.println("Second answer: " + (-b - d) / (2.0*a));
            } 
            else if (discriminant ==0.0) {
                System.out.println("First answer: " + (-b) / (2.0*a));
                System.out.println("Second answer: " + (-b) / (2.0*a));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("No answers");
                input.nextLine(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: take off the wildcards *.

Comment: I wonder when this `else if (discriminant == 0.0)` block will be entered ... is guess ... never?

Comment: well, I use 3 examples of equations, each of which falls under a certain discriminant result. if that's what youre asking...

Comment: So please look at your code and tell me _when_ this `else if` block will be entered.

Comment: honestly didn't get what you meant by your question, but the problem got fixed by other user's suggetion.

Comment: I mean that your `else if` block will _never_ be entered. You can remove it without changing your current program behaviour.

Comment: aaah i got it, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete

```
input.close();
```

When you close the `System.in` once, you can not use it again after having closing it.

---

I can not find the source but here is a proof that this is causing the problem.

Try running the following code and you'll get the exact same exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    input.close();
    Scanner other = new Scanner(System.in);
    other.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: i did so, but in that case program to every combination of numbers says "no answers"

Comment: @Evan this is another problem. Certainly with your algorithm. Accept this answer because it solves your problem and ask a new one concerning the algorithm. :)

Comment: thanks.
the thing is, when I had no " boolean go = true; while (go) {" , the program gave me correct answers. so I am not sure what can be wrong in the algorithm if it worked well and Eclipse didn't mention any errors, plus I am total newbie haha

Comment: @Evan well once you looped, you are asking more than once the use of System.in after having closing it.

Comment: okay, I'll just leave the code without the loop :\

Comment: @Evan You may still use your loop but you do not have to close the Scanner before your program ends... Do not forget to accept the answer :).

Comment: if I do not close the scanner, program always shows "no answers".

Comment: @TOm you're right. Thought this was the problem. Well, as I said, it is certainly a problem with the algo than.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Yes, we can just guess, since OP didn't even tell us which input he uses :(, but my bet is on a negative value in `discriminant` (obvious due to the "no answers" output :D) because of the formular  `b * b - 4 * a * c`.

Comment: the input.nextLine() worked! thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Evan Well, it makes no sense, that this should help, but since your used code doesn't match the code in the question we can't know what you're _really_ doing there.

Comment: my used code IS what's in the question. maybe I explained myself incorrectly somewhere, that made you think otherwise. though it now shows "resource leak:input never closed", but it works. I'm a quite bad student, I do not know what I'm doing half the time, sorry :(

Comment: *"my used code IS what's in the question."* ... *"I'll just leave the code without the loop"* ... no what is true here? ;P.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Even it is very strange that `nextLine` is the solution here, you should add this to your answer ... but I don't know how to write that, since it is unclear why this helps here :D.

Comment: I'd delete "bootlean=true while go{ "from the code. But now I still have the same code, just instead of "input.close();" there is "input.nextLine();"

Comment: @Evan So you removed the loop (therefore the program runs only once) and you wrote `input.nextLint();` into the `else` branch ... so what issue had this fixed? You said you always get *"no asnwers."*, but how should the new `nextLine` call fix that, if this happens right after the output?

Comment: now it gives correct answers and the program starts over after the answers were given.

Comment: @Evan It starts over? Without the loop? So you have more code than just this ... another method which calls this `main` method?

Comment: "I still have the same code", I mean there is still the  "bootlean=true while go{ ", the only thing that changed is NewLine instead of Close

Comment: So you still have the loop, ok. Now you removed `in.close` and with just `System.out.println("no asnwers.");` in the `else` branch you have an issue and if you add `in.nextLine()` to it, the issue is gone? If yes can you please provide example data so we can reproduce this problem?

Comment: I posted is an update for the question, the whole code(couldn't fit in as a comment).

Comment: @Evan It is preferable you post a new question because it is another problem.

Comment: @Evan I still don't see why you think that `input.nextLine();` is helping here, you can remove it without any harm. And please provide example data which to reproduce your former issuer. And about the other problem: there are already solution on Stackoverflow for that.

Answer (score 0):

When you call, `input.close()` it not only closes your scanner but closes your `System.in`. Now you still keep iterating over the loop even when scanner is closed (and keep scanning values) which causes excpetion.

**UPDATE**

Your code seems to go in a infinite loop because you do not break from the loop neither do you update the value of `go` which at some point might terminate the loop.

Thus, the `scanner` will keep reading values until all the inputs are exhausted and eventually throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception (when all the inputs are exhausted).

Comment: can i insert input.close() to another place so it would work?

Comment: @Evan: check the updates in my post

Comment: thanks for explanation. another answer helped me more.